# Shrink div content vertically as to fit in a certain height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cannot find a solution for implementing the following:Suppose we have a div (vertical sidebar) which occupies a percentage width, let's say 20%, of the viewport. Inside this div there is some stuff like a logo, a tree menu e.t.c. I want this div to have the height of the browser viewport (as to make it fixed). That means in case of small resolutions the div content has to shrink vertically as to fit in the smaller height. How may I achieve that?
You may have a look at http://lyk-ag-stefan.att.sch.gr/. Τhe blue sidebar corresponds to the above description.

I've tried some JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sheight = $(window).height();
    $('.sidebar').css("max-height", sheight);
});
```

Unfortunately, it did not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Div's need to know the height of the parent container

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
    border: 1px solid silver;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It does not work. The content goes underneath the visual viewport in small resolutions (e.g. 800x600)

Comment: @ILIAS If the content is too big to fit, do you want to increase the width of the container?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var _tmpResize;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".sidebar").css({
        height: jQuery(window).innerHeight()
    });
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(_tmpResize);
        _tmpResize = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.sidebar').css({
                height: jQuery(window).innerHeight()
            });
        }, 200); // trigger resize event only once
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jGXT5/)**

Your side bar will always have the same height of the viewport even after a `resize` event

Comment: If you shrink the content, then you will have it truncated. I guess you are looking for a sort of "vertical responsiveness", in that case you have to work out all the elements inside the content (fonts and images) with @media queries

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using the zoom property:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var sidebarHeight = $(".sidebar").outerHeight();
    var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
    $(".sidebar").css("zoom", (windowHeight/sidebarHeight + 0.3) );
});
```